# Permalink blog page (only) not working

Tags: permalinks, blog

WordPress 5.6, WooCommerce version 4.9.2, PHP Version 7.4.14

Dear,

I am facing a problem with permalinks. When having 'post name' selected, permalinks work for all pages expect 'blog'. In this case, no posts appear on the blog page. Only the page title. When having 'plain' permalinks selected, everything works like a charm.

I have troubleshooted by disabling plugins, using other themes, checking the .htaccess file on correct content/permissions, home/blog page correctly set in 'reading', but without success. I contacted my hosting company to check if mod_rewrite module is enabled and web directory override rule is set to AllowOverride All (waiting for their reply), but believe the problem is not on server level as other permalinks (e.g about & contact-us pages) work fine.

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Kind regards,
Quinten

EDIT: PROBLEM SOLVED

Comment: Quinten, would you like to answer your own question and explain how you solved the issue so other people who come across this can try the same solution on their sites?

Comment: Good idea. Thanks Tony

Answer (score 0):

The error **was** generated by the Elementor plugin. Setting 'Landing Pages' on Inactive in the Experiments menu in the Elementor settings did the job.